# Where has StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase gone?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

I'm porting C# code to a Windows Store App. To my surprise the following code does not work anymore:

```
someString.Equals("someOtherString", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

`InvariantCulture` and `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` have been removed(*) from `StringComparison`.

**Why?**

And how do I replace it?

Edit: (*) Strictly speaking, it has not been *removed*, it is merely *not available* for Windows Store Apps. The result is the same: You cannot use it.

Comment: What do you mean removed? It works on like `someString.Equals("someOtherString")` ?

Comment: Not ideal, but [people suggest using `OrdinalIgnoreCase` instead](https://nroute.svn.codeplex.com/svn/nRoute5/nRoute.Framework.Silverlight/Utilities/Compatability.cs).

Comment: @SonerGönül: The option `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` is not available

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Those specific options have not gone anywhere, but they are just not supported by Windows Store Apps.

If you look at MSDN for [StringComparison Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) you'll see those specific options are not supported by the Portable library or .NET for Windows Store.

The only options that are supported for the Portable Library or Windows Store Apps are:

- CurrentCulture
- CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
- Ordinal
- OrdinalIgnoreCase

I can't speak for why, but there is not an option to "replace" as those values do not exist within the framework.  You'll have to work with one of the other options that do exist, `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` is probably going to be the easiest to work with.

Comment: Thanks, now I know what to look for (green shopping bag).

Comment: I knnow; that's what I meant with "removed". But why and how to replace it. That's my question.

Comment: Replacing isn't an option, they don't exist in the framework.  You have to choose one of the other options that are supported by that framework.  As for why, I'm not really sure, haven;t dug into that too deeply before.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like it doesn't support Windows Store App.

For Windows Store App, only avaiable you can use with ***green bag*** enumerations;

[image]

For general idea, people used `OrdinalIgnoreCase` in this case.

https://github.com/loqu8/sqlite-net/commit/bfa04a6a40b4f62000bb9c57d5517643404c9109