# Doing a login with this code but can't try if it works because I cannot find "InvariantCultureIgnoreCase"

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am doing a login and I am trying to do it with a `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` but I get an error on `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`. `Xamarin` does not seem to find it. I am using System so that does not seem to be the problem.

```
var userInfo = await parseAPI.loginUser (usernameEntry.Text, passwordEntry.Text);

if (String.Equals (usernameEntry.Text, yourEmail.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) 
{
    if (userInfo ["error"] == null)
    {
        Application.Current.Properties ["userId"] = userInfo ["objectId"].ToString ();
        Application.Current.Properties ["sessionToken"] = userInfo ["sessionToken"].ToString ();
        await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync ();
        App.ourUsername = usernameEntry.Text; 
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (App.ourUsername);               
        Navigation.PopModalAsync ();        
    } 
    else 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where has StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase gone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600694/where-has-stringcomparison-invariantcultureignorecase-gone)

Comment: If the user does not type their username exactly, won't the Parse login fail?  What is the point of what you're doing if that happens?

Comment: that is what iam trying to fix. now it works if u type the exact thing, so for example if u register as "m" and u login as "M" it wont work, but if u type "m" instead, it will work.

Comment: You need to modify the case of the username **BEFORE** you call the parse login function

Comment: Hmm, okay. So here then, where I register?
http://pastebin.com/WNVdW362

Comment: If you register with "Bob", and login with with "bob", login is going to fail (I assume Parse is case sensitive).  To avoid this, you need to force the case of the username to either all lower or all upper **whenever you pass the username to parse**

Comment: Yes it fails exactly. I have a code that is supposed to do that but it doesnt make a change. Here is the code, as u can see I am doing what u are explaining on my "logincode". http://pastebin.com/4gT5QXk8

Comment: you are passing yourEmail.Text to Parse - presumably this is the exact text the user entered, without being forced into upper/lower case.

Comment: hm okok. so I should add a piece of code to the registerfunction instead of the "loginfunction"?

Comment: **every time you pass username to parse** you need to be sure that you are using a consistent case

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean but I am not quite sure how to execute it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse is case sensitive - that means if you want your login to be case-insensitive **YOUR CODE** needs to handle that, not Parse.  The easiest way to do this is to always enforce a consistent casing scheme (either lower or upper).

```
// Registration - force the user's input to lcase
string username = UserRegControl.Text.ToLower();
var userInfo = await parseAPI.signupUser (username, yourPassword.Text );

// Login - again, force user's input to lcase to match registration
string username = UserLoginControl.Text.ToLower();
var userInfo = await parseAPI.loginUser (username, passwordEntry.Text);
```

Comment: Ok but how will "username" find my 2 different entries? first my registerentry (named yourEmail.Text) and loginentry (named usernameEntry.Text)

Comment: UserRegControl & UserLoginControl - replace these with whatever names you are using for your controls.

Comment: Ah okay. and the strings can be named username and username1 then? As they dont have to be identical

Comment: you can name them whatever you want.  Presumably you will be using them in different methods, so they will not conflict if they are named the same thing.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks alot, Jason.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you better use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` ?

Comment: Yeah, it is running now but the code does not seem to work however.

Comment: Do u know what the proble might be? usernameentry is the logininfo and youremail.text is the registerinfo

Comment: And are you shure App.ourUsername and yourEmail.Text should be equals? Try to get both of them on the console.

Comment: youremail.text is taken from textbox?

Comment: this is the code: (String.Equals (usernameEntry.Text, yourEmail.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))

Comment: youremail is a entry where u register ur "username" and usernameentry is where u put the registered name

Comment: it works but only if i type identical (so if i register wiht a "m" i can login if i type "m" but not "M")

Comment: so try to use StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase

Comment: If it won't work we could make something like String.Equals ( (usernameEntry.Text).ToString().Toupper(), yourEmail.TextToString().Toupper(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

Comment: Still does not work with that code V.borisov. i come online if i type a small "i" if i registered with a "i", not if i type "I"